# Change source address on discovery of network devices in System Center Operations Manager 2012

Tags: ping, network-monitoring, scom, system-center, discovery

My SCOM server has two network cards. One is normal network while the other is connected to the "switch" VLAN. If I try discovering network devices in SCOM I get "No Response Ping", no matter which switch I try to discover. From the server I'm able to ping the switch, but not if I use the "-S" flag (source address) and set the source address to the normal network card.
How can I "tell" SCOM to use the other network card, or maybe both, when discovering network devices?

Answer (score 0):

I found this blog post http://www.code4ward.net/main/Blog/tabid/70/EntryId/105/Troubleshooting-Network-Discovery-in-SCOM-2012.aspx
Added ping.exe and monitorhost.exe as allowed in the firewall and everything worked perfectly!